# Why did the layers menu disappear?

Tags: layers

In the bottom of the screen I cant see my layers anymore. I switch to all local, global,etc but I can't find the layer menu. When I press <kbd>M</kbd> to move my object I get a message: **Move from localview**

How can I get the layer menu back?

[image]
[image]

Comment: press the / key in the numpad to exit local view

Comment: @cegaton That was great. Can u tell me how it hide